# Spatial regression using GAM in R

Tags: spatial-interaction-model

I have some spatial data, that is a value for a dependent variable y, vs an independent variable x, along with lat, longs for the measurement. Y is a quadratic function of x, but the nature of the relationship is in turn a function of space. I have been looking at a few options and using the GAM function in mgcv in R. My goal is to fit

```
y = a+b*x+c*x^2 + s(lat) + s(long)              Model 1
```

Where s(lat) and s(long) are some smoothed functions of lat, long.

Really though, the coefficients a,b and c vary as the lat longs vary, but I am not sure how to set up the problem. I looked into GWR or the geographically weighted regression but was told that its not a very stable technique. One question I do have is the difference between the above model and the following model,

```
y = a+b*x+c*x^2 + s(lat,long)                      Model 2
```

And which one makes more sense or is more robust? Also how does one interpret the plot(model) function graph for the 2-d Interaction case as in the above model.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by the "2-d interaction case"? I see no interactions in either of your models. (An interaction would be a term of the form `x*s(lat)`, `x*s(long)`, `x^2*s(lat)`, or `x^2*s(long)` in the first model, or comparable terms in the second model.)

Comment: Oh I meant s(lat,long) as the interaction term.

Comment: The distinction is crucial for your question: if you want the coefficients to vary with (lat, lon) then you need interactions in the (standard) sense that I described. So far, you have only introduced location as a *covariate*, not as an interaction.

Comment: Basically I tried the following model also,  m1 = gam(y~x*s(lat)+s(lat)*I(x^2)). But ran into this, Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + x:s(lat) + lat,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 's(lat)'. Also I understand that specifying the term s(lat,long) is like adding a separate covariate, but how is that different from s(long) and s(lat) individually in context of model 1 above.

Comment: Don't let syntax errors cause you to change the model! Who is to be in control of your analysis--you or the computer? Debug your code instead.  (Because functions of the form `s(lat,lon)` include additive functions `s(lon)+s(lat)`, they are more general.)

Comment: well good point, then why does the overall deviance of the s(lat,lon) model higher than s(lat) + s(lon). it seems that former should be a superset of the latter and should give a lower deviance or a better fit.

Comment: Most likely because you may have chosen *one particular smooth* `s(lat,lon)` that is not as good a fit as `s(lat)+s(lon)`. More generally, you gain flexibility--at some cost in degrees of freedom--by using "splined" fits where these functions are replaced by smooths with only local support (that is, the places where their values change are within spatially confined regions) whose supports collectively cover the entire region of interest. You would need to provide details of your smooths if you want a specific answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks whuber, would you mind moving this to chat? I think I can benefit for your understanding a lot. Part of the problem is that I am new to gams fitting.

Comment: I just used s(lat,long) vs s(lat) + s(long). I don't know in general which smooth functions to specify and such.